# Cargar un archivo TxT con datos y pasar estos a un Textbox

Tags: visual-studio

Veréis, necesito hacer lo siguiente.
Mi nivel de programación en esto es mínimo puesto que sólo hemos seguido una pequeña guía proporcionada por el profesor y no cubre la mayoría de las cosas escritas aquí. Sólo la de guardar.

Guardar datos en un txt por ejemplo. Hecho y funcional.
Abrir el Txt. (No sé)
Cargar datos del Txt a diferentes TextBox (No sé)

Guarda Nombre: {0} (lo que haya escrito en el programa) Y se guarda con el buscador de archivos donde yo le indique.

Ahora necesito saber como abrir ese txt. Usando el buscador de archivos.`

```
        SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveDialog.DefaultExt = "txt";
        saveDialog.AddExtension = true;
        saveDialog.FileName = textboxApellidos.Text;
        saveDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\Javier\Documents\";
        saveDialog.OverwritePrompt = true;
        saveDialog.Title = "Citas";
        saveDialog.ValidateNames = true;
        if (saveDialog.ShowDialog().Value)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveDialog.FileName))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Nombre: {0}", textboxNombre.Text);
                writer.WriteLine("Apellido: {0}", textboxApellidos.Text);
                if (hombreCB.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Sexo: {0}", hombreCB.Content.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Sexo: {0}", mujerCB.Content.ToString());
                }
                writer.WriteLine("Próxima cita: {0}", proximaCita.Text);
                writer.WriteLine("Sintomas:{0} ", textboxSintomas.Text);
                writer.WriteLine("Diagnóstico:{0} ", textboxDiagnostico.Text);

                writer.WriteLine("Doctor: {0}", doctorsCB.Text);

                MessageBox.Show("Cita guardada.");

            }
        }

    }`
```

Este es el código para guardarlo, pero soy incapaz de averiguar como abrirlo y mucho menos de cargar los datos que he guardado en un textbox. Cualquier ayuda sería genial.

Este es el nuevo código que he creado con la ayuda de una respuesta. 
` private void AccederCita_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\" ;
openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;
 StreamReader fp; char[] buffer = new char[160]; int i = 0; string texto; string[] split = null; bool bok = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == true)
{
            string line;
            string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            fp = new StreamReader(filename);
            if (fp != null)
            {
                Paciente concita = new Paciente();
                concita.ShowDialog();
                i = 0;
                do
                {
                    texto = fp.ReadLine();
                    i++;
                    if (texto != null)
                    {
                        if (texto.Length > 2)
                        {
                            split = texto.Split(';');

                            concita.textboxNombre.Text = split[0];
                            concita.textboxApellidos.Text = split[1];
                           // concita.textboxSexo.Text = split[2];
                            concita.textboxSintomas.Text = split[3];
                            concita.textboxDiagnostico.Text = split[4];
                        }
                    }
                } while (!fp.EndOfStream);
            }
            fp.Close();

            if (i > 1)
                MessageBox.Show("Carga de archivo terminada..." + i.ToString());
        }

    }`
```

Se abre el buscador de archivos, selecciono la cita y se abre una nueva ventana pero los datos no se rellenan, además al cerrar la ventana de cita da un error.

Comment: Pero entonces el código que publicas no está relacionado con tus dos problemas. Te recomiendo primero que hagas una pregunta diferente para cada problema que enfrentes. Luego que incluyas el código que permita reproducir el problema que enfrentas, ojo, no cualquier código, sino el que permita observar como estás resolviendo el problema (usa [esta guía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Si buscas ideas o no sabes por donde empezar, te recomiendo que uses Google.

Comment: No, no lo está, está relacionado con el txt que se crea con lo que sé hacer, pero no con lo que no tengo ni idea, y todo lo que encuentro por internet utiliza forms y la palabra "Dim",etc. Por lo cual no puedo aplicarlo a mi trabajo.  

Resumiendo: Necesito hacer un código que me permita mediante el buscador de archivos abrir un txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> si tienes un archivo plano(txt) con la informacion separada por punto y coma 
>   el método en c# puede ser como el siguiente:

```
public void Download(string fileName)
        {
            StreamReader fp;
            char[] buffer = new char[160];
            int i = 0;
            string texto;
            string[] split = null;
            bool bok = true;

            fp = new StreamReader(fileName);
            if (fp != null)
            {
                i = 0;
                do
                {
                    texto = fp.ReadLine();
                    i++;
                    if (texto != null)
                    {
                        if (texto.Length > 2)
                        {
                            split = texto.Split(';');

                            textboxNombre.Text      = split[0];
                            textboxApellidos.Text   = split[1];
                            textboxSexo.Text        = split[2];
                            textboxSintomas.Text    = split[3];
                            textboxDiagnostico.Text = split[4];
                        }
                    }
                } while (!fp.EndOfStream);
            }
            fp.Close();
            frm.Close();
            if (i > 1)
                    MessageBox.Show("Carga de archivo terminada..."+i.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Tú código parece ser la solución  pero si miras mi edit soy incapaz de que haga lo que debe. Soy un negado para esto.

Comment: Solucionado, tu comentario me ha servido de mucho, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

> Mira este fragmento de como se llama un archivo plano y luego hace la carga
>   El método DownLoad() es el que te había enviado anteriormente
>   Yo te recomiendo que hagas dos métodos, uno para grabar, y otra para subir datos
>   Este es el método para subir datos

```
private void SubirDatos()
{

DialogResult result;

OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Browse Ascii Files";

openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (.asc)|*.txt|All Files (*.asc)|*.*";
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;

openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";

result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
     Download(openFileDialog1.FileName.Trim());
}
}
```